# How do I synchronise my Raspberry Pi File System to a directory on my Mac?

Tags: pi-2, ssh, filesystem

Is there a way to keep my RPi File System in sync with a directory on my Mac? Can I do this with rsync? (I write most code on the RPi, and would like a copy of it on my Mac, in case I corrupt the SD card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is **No**.

If you search you will find a couple of posts on this. I tried unsuccessfully for some time.

It is possible to `rsync` your Home, but in general it will not work.
There are a couple of reasons for this;

1. `rsync` differs quite significantly between Unix and Linux
2. The users differ between the systems, making permissions difficult.
3. The **most significant** reason is the restrictions macOS imposes due to SIP. It simply **refuses** to allow access to certain directories e.g. `/`.

You may be able to `rsync` certain directories on the Pi, provided they are normal user directories, with no special access restrictions.

I suggest you try other options; `netatalk` on the Pi allows you to access from `Finder` using `afp://`. `ftp` is also a useful.

In general macOS does not like files with execute permissions and refuses to edit `bash` scripts, even though they are plain text.

Comment: I tried samba. I can connect to my Pi, but cannot edit any files, although I changed the permissions of them on the Pi. Do I need to do anything on my Mac? I have found samba the easiest.

Comment: @NullCoderExists I can't comment on Samba (I haven't used it for years, and found it a PITA). Using `afp` I can edit most files (exceptions being those with execute permission - which means most on FAT partitions, and those in "protected" directories, which violate some macOS foible). In practice I copy files to the Mac, change permissions, restore copied file. This is also a PITA but, in practice, does not affect many files.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something called `sshfs` which allows you to mount a distant volume. Install this on your Mac then you should be able to mount a distant (RPI) folder to your local file system (Mac)